# save files from a website directory

Tags: java, url

There are examples for JMH [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/f4e8d0d61f1f/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/). They are present as multiple links within the directory samples/. I can right click on the link and save the files one by one. Is there any way to save all of them at once? Rather than using any download managers! Can we use Java URL class with regex to open the similarly named files and save it?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j

Comment: Um, that's a Mercurial web view. So, why can't you clone the JMH workspace? `hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/ jmh`